# @Cacheable : how to pass a new attribute that can be used in my own KeyGenerator?

Tags: spring, caching, key-generator, spring-cache

I need your expertise :)

I'm working on a application where method calls on a service need to be authenticated.
That means I want each method call to be cached with a key containing the username (to avoid for an unauthorized user to retrieve information cached by an authorized one).

With a personnalized KeyGenerator, all works fine.

Example of my key : *username:USERNAME.appVersion:VERSION.METHOD.PARAM1.etc*

But at some location, I got methods that retrieve a national content : this one will be the same for each user. And I want to avoid a cache key for each user asking for this content.

Example : *appVersion:VERSION.METHOD.PARAM1.etc*

So when I'm positioning my @Cacheable annotations, is there any way to set a new parameter in it ? The Key Generator will be able to catch it and know if he had to prefix the cache key name with user information or not.

Thanks for your help :)

Take care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're saying by "set a new parameter in it". That parameter should come from somewhere right?

`KeyGenerator` gives you access to the `Method`, the actual instance and the method arguments. You may want to have a specific `KeyGenerator` for this particular cache operation which is something that [will be available as from Spring 4.1](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10629) but in the mean time you can implement a composite that invokes the right `KeyGenerator` instance based on the method or, for instance, an annotation you have created to flag it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you snicoll, that was crystal clear and you really helped me a lot :)

Waiting for Spring 4.1, my team and I decided to use a custom @SharedCache annotation.

Here is some code samples to help if someone is in the same situation.

- Given an existing custom GenericKeyGenerator (he's building a custom cache key for each cached method invocation)
- We have a new custom AuthenticatedGenericKeyGenerator : he's inherited from GenericKeyGenerator and simply prefixing the cache key with user information

The application is now using AuthenticatedGenericKeyGenerator by default :

```
<cache:annotation-driven key-generator="keyGenerator"/>

<bean id="keyGenerator" class="your.package.AuthenticatedGenericKeyGenerator" />
```

AuthenticatedGenericKeyGenerator.java in details :

```
public class AuthenticatedGenericKeyGenerator extends GenericKeyGenerator {

    public AuthenticatedGenericKeyGenerator() {

        super(...);
    }

    @Override
    public Object generate(final Object target, final Method method, final Object... params) {

        String cacheKey = super.generate(target, method, params).toString();

        if(!method.isAnnotationPresent(SharedCache.class)) {

            cacheKey =  "user:" + some user information + "." + cacheKey;
        }

        return cacheKey;
    }

}
```

Our custom @SharedCache annotation :

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface SharedCache {

}
```

Now we just have to annotate @Cacheable methods with an extra @SharedCache if we want the cache key to be shared and not be unique (with an user id for example).

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant, nice! The feature I was talking about is now available in the latest `4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` so if these are only related to certain classes you can just as well customize the key generator at class level now (i.e. `@CacheConfig(keyGenerator = "authGenericKeyGenerator")`)